# Why doesn't C++ std::set have an 'at' function and what is the inline alternative

Tags: c++

Consider the following code

```
std::map<int, std::string> someMap;
[... populate the map ...]

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int stringNumber)
    : mString(someMap.at(stringNumber))
    {}

private:
    std::string mString;
};
```

Now suppose I want to refactor using a class like this

```
struct StringWithID
{
    int stringID;
    std::string stringValue;
}
inline bool operator<(const StringWithID& l, const StringWithID& r) { return l.stringID < r.stringID;}
```

And suppose I want to replace stringMap with

```
std::set<StringWithID> someSet;
```

Now I cannot write `someSet.at(stringNumber)`

My questions are

- Why is the 'at' function not available for std::set?
- In my use case above, I am looking for a single function call that can be used during the initializer list, I want it to be safe and throw (instead of UB) if my element is not found.  How can I do this with a std::set?

Comment: That cannot happen because std::set is a unique, ordered set.

Comment: `at` doesn't really make sense for a `std::set`. If you want to get the element in the set that is equivalent to a value you can use `find` to get an iterator to it.

Comment: find returns an iterator, if you dereference an end iter then it is UB.  That is the whole reason `at` was added to the other containers (to provide shorthand for checking the end iter and throwing it it is the end iter).  It makes perfect sense to add `at` it to `std::set` to me.  It's exactly like adding it to `std::map`

Comment: Not really. For a `std::map`, `at` is asking for the element at a given key. Since `std::set` just has keys you already have the key, so what's the point in asking for it? `std::set` was not designed for what you're trying to do. Use `std::map` instead like you were before.

Comment: OK, you're right.  I'm being stupid.  I guess I should just delete the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is the 'at' function not available for std::set?

If you already have a value, what do you want to get? It's only a set of numbers. There is no key you can look up by. What you're looking for is a `std::map`

> I want it to be safe and throw
>   (instead of UB) if my element is not found. How can I do this with a
>   std::set?

Since `std::set` is not made for what you're trying to accomplish you have to use `std::set::find()`. It returns `std::set::end()` if element is not found. If you really need to throw just make a helper function.

I fail to see why you just don't want to use `std::map` though.

Answer (score 1):

The `map` relates a key to a value.  [`map::at()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/) provides you a reference to the value for an existing key, which you could perfectly modify, and throws an exception if the value doesn't exist.

The `set` only keeps key which are in the set. An element is in the set or it is not. It's a little bit like a map where all the values would be true, and you could not change this value.  So by construction it can't have a an `at`-like semantic.

**Alternatives**

1. The closest semantic to the `at()` would be to use [`set::count()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/count/) which returns 1 if the key is in the set and 0 if not (a value, not a reference). You could then easily throw if its the wrong value.  You could even have a template function that does this for you.
2. Refactor your code to use a `map<string, bool>` instead of a set, and populate the map with `true` for each item you add.